# PySpark: are different transformation on a kafka read dataframe working on the same data?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am new to spark and I have a question about the **load** behavior when dealing with kafka batch API: suppose I am reading the dataframe in this way:

```
    df = spark.read \
            .format("kafka") \
            .option("subscribe", topic_name) \ # many other options follows
            .load()
```

I want to perform different transformations on it: for instance extracting the last offset read from each partition, and manipulate the data to create some parquet files:

```
    aggregates = df.groupBy("partition").max("offset").collect()
    
    # some filtering on df and finally
    
    df.write.parquet(target_path)
```

My understanding is that the data will be actually read just once when **load** is called, and then the aggregate and write will work on the same data. If during the processing new events are pushed to kafka, they will be ignored.

Is this correct, or actually the **collect** and **write.parquet** will re-trigger the loading, and they can see different sets of kafka events?

Comment: _If during the processing new events are pushed to kafka, they will be ignored_ - This is why you use `spark.readStream`

Comment: Ignore new events would be fine in my case, just I want to be sure that the grouping and the write works on the same data.

Comment: It should. Are you not seeing this? Also, this will only find the max offset _per batch_, not the current max offset of each partition in the Kafka cluster. Assuming, you are expecting to use those values to notify yourself when the consumption is "complete"

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time to try it and see what is happening. Here the databricks notebook I used to test

```
# Databricks notebook source
# MAGIC %md
# MAGIC Let's read some data from the real topic and put 1000 lines in the topic_test, to play with it

# COMMAND ----------

truststore = '****'
trustStorePasword = '****'

source_data = spark.read \
            .format("kafka") \
            .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", truststore) \
            .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", trustStorePasword) \
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "****") \
            .option("kafka.security.protocol", "ssl") \
            .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.type", "PKCS12") \
            .option("subscribe", "sometopic") \
            .load() 



# COMMAND ----------

source_data \
    .limit(1000) \
    .select("key","value") \
    .write \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", truststore) \
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", trustStorePasword) \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "****") \
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", "ssl") \
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.type", "PKCS12") \
    .option("topic", "topic_test") \
    .save()

# COMMAND ----------

# MAGIC %md
# MAGIC Now let's read from topic_test and compute the aggregate

# COMMAND ----------

df = spark.read \
            .format("kafka") \
            .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", truststore) \
            .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", trustStorePasword) \
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "****") \
            .option("kafka.security.protocol", "ssl") \
            .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.type", "PKCS12") \
            .option("subscribe", "topic_test") \
            .load() 


# COMMAND ----------

display(df.groupBy("partition").max("offset").collect())

# COMMAND ----------

df.count() # shows 1000

# COMMAND ----------

# MAGIC %md
# MAGIC Let's push again some data to topic_test - we will se if there will be a change in the count

# COMMAND ----------

source_data \
    .limit(100) \
    .select("key","value") \
    .write \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", truststore) \
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", trustStorePasword) \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "****") \
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", "ssl") \
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.type", "PKCS12") \
    .option("topic", "topic_test") \
    .save()

# COMMAND ----------

# MAGIC %md
# MAGIC count should be 1000

# COMMAND ----------

df.count() # it's 1100
```

So it reads again the data and the two operations can see different things. I tried again adding a .cache after the first load and with that the count did not change.